# передача булевого параметра в качестве аргумента конструктора

Tags: c#, конструктор

C# смотрю курс по рефакторингу от itvdn. есть класс:

```
class Car(){
 bool isSportCar;
...
 Car(bool isSportCar){
  this.isSportCar = isSportCar;
 }
...
}
```

вызов метода-конструктора вышеуказанного класса с указанием булевого значения в качестве параметра аргумента:

```
Car fastCar = new Car(isSportCar: true);
```

смущает элементарно сам формат передачи: УКАЗАНИЕ имени переменной, ДВОЕТОЧИЕ... первый раз вижу вместо обычного значения. Дайте ссылку на мсдн кто знает, сам не найду...

Comment: Язык-то какой?.. И оформите код, пожалуйста.

Comment: Именованные параметры https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd264739.aspx

Comment: C#. Исправил. Отдельный раздел не нашёл. Не пинайте вопрос, я вообще не спрашиваю обычно. О! Спасибо. Если не знает порядок! точно. туплю. ок к

Comment: @vitidev: Может, напишете ответ?

Comment: Так Вы же сами ответили. Вот текст по ссылке:Если разработчик не помнит порядок параметров, но знает их имена, он может передать аргументы в любом порядке, сначала указав вес или рост.
CalculateBMI(weight: 123, height: 64);

Comment: а, ну да, это же не мне вопрос. Тогда добавлю к @vitidev 4ое: после именованных параметров нельзя ставить позиционные: Именованный аргумент можно поместить после позиционных аргументов, как показано ниже.
CalculateBMI(123, height: 64);
Однако позиционные аргументы нельзя размещать после именованных аргументов. Следующая инструкция вызывает ошибку компилятора.
//CalculateBMI(weight: 123, 64); ура товарищи!

Answer (score 3):

Это [именованные параметры](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd264739.aspx). Полезны в случаях

1. Когда нужно акцентировать внимание на параметре, чтобы читающий сразу понимал, что означает true.
2. Позволяет вызывать параметры в ином порядке.
3. Если метод принимает много параметров с дефолтными значениями, то так можно указать только нужные. (без именованных параметров чтобы заполнить 5 позиционный параметр придется заполнить предыдущие 4, даже если у них есть дефолтные значения)